# Counter for while loop

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$num = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultItem) && $num != 0)
{ 
    echo $num++;
?>
    <b><?php echo $row['author']; ?></b>
    <br>
    <i><?php echo $row['description']; ?></i>
    <br>
    <?php echo $row['research_place']; ?>
        <br>
        <a href="<?php echo $row['pdf']; ?>">PDF</a>

<?php } ?>
```

My author, description, research place pdf cant be fetch. :/

My outputs shows as follows:
Publications by Research Area

There are 85 publications
1

PDF

2

PDF

3

PDF

4

PDF

5

PDF

6

PDF

7

PDF

8

PDF

9

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Show your full query and code.

Comment: Apparently your result does not contain author/description/... fields. Paste the query and the code that executes that and then we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood,
try this

```
<?php
    $num = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultItem))
    {

        ?>
        <b><?php echo $row['author']; ?></b> <br>
        <i><?php echo $row['description']; ?></i> <br>
        <?php echo $row['research_place']; ?> <br>
        <a href = "<?php echo $row['pdf']; ?>">PDF</a>

        <?php
        $num += 1;
    }
    echo 'Count is: '.$num;
?>
```